# How to select using WITH RECURSIVE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have googled and read throug some articles like 
[this postgreSQL manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)
or [this blog page](http://gennick.com/with.html)
and tried making queries myself with a moderate success (part of them hangs, while others works good and fast), 
but so far I can not *completely* understand how this *magic* works.

Can anybody give very clear explanation demonstrating such query semantics and execution process,
better based on typical samples like factorial calculation or full tree expansion from `(id,parent_id,name)` table?

And what are the basic guidlines and typical mistakes that one should know to make good `with recursive` queries?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First of all, let us try to simplify and clarify algorithm description given on the [manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html). To simplify it consider only `union all` in `with recursive` clause for now (and `union` later):

```
WITH RECURSIVE pseudo-entity-name(column-names) AS (
    Initial-SELECT
UNION ALL
    Recursive-SELECT using pseudo-entity-name
)
Outer-SELECT using pseudo-entity-name
```

To clarify it let us describe query execution process in pseudo code:

```
working-recordset = result of Initial-SELECT

append working-recordset to empty outer-recordset

while( working-recordset is not empty ) begin

    new working-recordset = result of Recursive-SELECT 
        taking previous working-recordset as pseudo-entity-name

    append working-recordset to outer-recordset

end

overall-result = result of Outer-SELECT 
    taking outer-recordset as pseudo-entity-name
```

Or even shorter - Database engine executes initial select, taking its result rows as working set. Then it repeatedly executes recursive select on the working set, each time replacing contents of the working set with query result obtained. This process ends when empty set is returned by recursive select. And all result rows given firstly by initial select and then by recursive select are gathered and feeded to outer select, which result becomes overall query result.

This query is calculating **factorial** of 3:

```
WITH RECURSIVE factorial(F,n) AS (
    SELECT 1 F, 3 n
UNION ALL
    SELECT F*n F, n-1 n from factorial where n>1
)
SELECT F from factorial where n=1
```

Initial select `SELECT 1 F, 3 n` gives us initial values: 3 for argument and 1 for function value.

Recursive select `SELECT F*n F, n-1 n from factorial where n>1` states that every time we need to multiply last funcion value by last argument value and decrement argument value.

Database engine executes it like this:

First of all it executes initail select, which gives the initial state of working recordset:

```
F | n
--+--
1 | 3
```

Then it transforms working recordset with recursive query and obtain its second state:

```
F | n
--+--
3 | 2
```

Then third state:

```
F | n
--+--
6 | 1
```

In the third state there is no row which follows `n>1` condition in recursive select, so forth working set is loop exits.

Outer recordset now holds all the rows, returned by initial and recursive select:

```
F | n
--+--
1 | 3
3 | 2
6 | 1
```

Outer select filters out all intermediate results from outer recordset, showing only final factorial value which becomes overall query result:

```
F 
--
6
```

And now let us consider table `forest(id,parent_id,name)`:

```
id | parent_id | name
---+-----------+-----------------
1  |           | item 1
2  | 1         | subitem 1.1
3  | 1         | subitem 1.2
4  | 1         | subitem 1.3
5  | 3         | subsubitem 1.2.1
6  |           | item 2
7  | 6         | subitem 2.1
8  |           | item 3
```

'**Expanding full tree**' here means sorting tree items in human-readable depth-first order while calculating their levels and (maybe) paths. Both tasks (of correct sorting and calculating level or path) are not solvable in one (or even any constant number of) SELECT without using WITH RECURSIVE clause (or Oracle CONNECT BY clause, which is not supported by PostgreSQL). But this recursive query does the job (well, almost does, see the note below):

```
WITH RECURSIVE fulltree(id,parent_id,level,name,path) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, 1 as level, name, name||'' as path from forest where parent_id is null
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, ft.level+1 as level, t.name, ft.path||' / '||t.name as path
    from forest t, fulltree ft where t.parent_id = ft.id
)
SELECT * from fulltree order by path
```

Database engine executes it like this:

Firstly, it executes initail select, which gives all highest level items (roots) from `forest` table:

```
id | parent_id | level | name             | path
---+-----------+-------+------------------+----------------------------------------
1  |           | 1     | item 1           | item 1
8  |           | 1     | item 3           | item 3
6  |           | 1     | item 2           | item 2
```

Then, it executes recursive select, which gives all 2nd level items from `forest` table:

```
id | parent_id | level | name             | path
---+-----------+-------+------------------+----------------------------------------
2  | 1         | 2     | subitem 1.1      | item 1 / subitem 1.1
3  | 1         | 2     | subitem 1.2      | item 1 / subitem 1.2
4  | 1         | 2     | subitem 1.3      | item 1 / subitem 1.3
7  | 6         | 2     | subitem 2.1      | item 2 / subitem 2.1
```

Then, it executes recursive select again, retrieving 3d level items:

```
id | parent_id | level | name             | path
---+-----------+-------+------------------+----------------------------------------
5  | 3         | 3     | subsubitem 1.2.1 | item 1 / subitem 1.2 / subsubitem 1.2.1
```

And now it executes recursive select again, trying to retrieve 4th level items, but there are none of them, so the loop exits.

The outer SELECT sets the correct human-readable row order, sorting on path column:

```
id | parent_id | level | name             | path
---+-----------+-------+------------------+----------------------------------------
1  |           | 1     | item 1           | item 1
2  | 1         | 2     | subitem 1.1      | item 1 / subitem 1.1
3  | 1         | 2     | subitem 1.2      | item 1 / subitem 1.2
5  | 3         | 3     | subsubitem 1.2.1 | item 1 / subitem 1.2 / subsubitem 1.2.1
4  | 1         | 2     | subitem 1.3      | item 1 / subitem 1.3
6  |           | 1     | item 2           | item 2
7  | 6         | 2     | subitem 2.1      | item 2 / subitem 2.1
8  |           | 1     | item 3           | item 3
```

**NOTE**: Resulting row order will remain correct only while there are no punctuation characters collation-preceeding `/` in the item names. If we rename `Item 2` in `Item 1 *`, it will break row order, standing between `Item 1` and its descendants.

More stable solution is using tab character (`E'\t'`) as path separator in query (which can be substituted by more readable path separator later: in outer select, before displaing to human or etc). Tab separated paths will retain correct order until there are tabs or control characters in the item names - which easily can be checked and ruled out without loss of usability.

It is very simple to modify last query to expand any arbitrary subtree - you need only to substitute condition `parent_id is null` with `perent_id=1` (for example). Note that this query variant will return all levels and paths *relative to* `Item 1`.

And now about **typical mistakes**. The most notable typical mistake specific to recursive queries is defining ill stop conditions in recursive select, which results in infinite looping.

For example, if we omit `where n>1` condition in factorial sample above, execution of recursive select will never give an empty set (because we have no condition to filter out single row) and looping will continue infinitely.

That is the most probable reason why some of your queries hang (the other non-specific but still possible reason is very ineffective select, which executes in finite but very long time).

There are not much RECURSIVE-specific querying **guidlines** to mention, as far as I know. But I would like to suggest (rather obvious) step by step recursive query building procedure.

- Separately build and debug your initial select.
- Wrap it with scaffolding WITH RECURSIVE construct 

  and begin building and debugging your recursive select.

The recommended scuffolding construct is like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec( <Your column names> ) AS (
    <Your ready and working initial SELECT>
UNION ALL
    <Recursive SELECT that you are debugging now>
)
SELECT * from rec limit 1000
```

This simplest outer select will output the whole outer recordset, which, as we know, contains all output rows from initial select and every execution of recusrive select in a loop in their original output order - just like in samples above!  The `limit 1000` part will prevent hanging, replacing it with oversized output in which you will be able to see the missed stop point.

- After debugging initial and recursive select build and debug your outer select.

And now the last thing to mention - the difference in using **`union`** instead of `union all` in `with recursive` clause. It introduces row uniqueness constraint which results in two extra lines in our execution pseudocode:

```
working-recordset = result of Initial-SELECT

discard duplicate rows from working-recordset /*union-specific*/

append working-recordset to empty outer-recordset

while( working-recordset is not empty ) begin

    new working-recordset = result of Recursive-SELECT 
        taking previous working-recordset as pseudo-entity-name

    discard duplicate rows and rows that have duplicates in outer-recordset 
        from working-recordset /*union-specific*/

    append working-recordset to outer-recordset

end

overall-result = result of Outer-SELECT 
    taking outer-recordset as pseudo-entity-name
```

Comment: It should be available in an official documentation ;)