# SQL Order by parent and child

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

Basically I need help in my query here. I want to be in right order which is child must be under parents name and in A-Z order. But if I add a `subChild` under child (`Split 1`) seem the order is wrong. It should be under `Room Rose`.

p/s : A subChild also can create another subChild

[HERE I PROVIDE A DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf72b/6)

Appreciate your help me get this ordered correctly?

```
SELECT A.venueID
     , B.mainVenueID
     , A.venueName 
  FROM tblAdmVenue A 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tblAdmVenueLink B
    ON A.venueID = B.subVenueID
 ORDER   
    BY COALESCE(B.mainVenueID, A.venueID)
     , B.mainVenueID IS NOT NULL
     , A.venueID
```

[image]

I want it return an order something like this.

```
venueName
--------------
Banquet
Big Room
-Room Daisy
-Room Rose
  -Split 1
Hall
-Meeting Room WP
```

Seem this recursive approach also in not working

```
WITH venue_ctg AS (
  SELECT A.venueID, A.venueName, B.mainVenueID 
  FROM tblAdmVenue A LEFT JOIN tblAdmVenueLink B
  ON A.venueID = B.subVenueID
  WHERE B.mainVenueID IS NULL 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT A.venueID, A.venueName, B.mainVenueID 
  FROM tblAdmVenue A LEFT JOIN tblAdmVenueLink B
  ON A.venueID = B.subVenueID
  WHERE B.mainVenueID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM venue_ctg ORDER BY venueName
```

output given

[image]

Comment: You can use a recursive query to accomplish your task - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: I try the recursive answer and still not working

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your data ordered in alphabetical order and depth first.

A common solution for this is to traverse the structure from the top element, concatenating the path to each item as you go. You can then directly use the path for ordering.

Here is how to do it in MySQL 8.0 with a recursive query

```
with recursive cte(venueID, venueName, mainVenueID, path, depth) as (
    select v.venueID, v.venueName, cast(null as char(100)), venueName, 0
    from tblAdmVenue v
    where not exists (select 1 from tblAdmVenueLink l where l.subVenueID = v.venueID)
    union all
    select v.venueID, v.venueName, c.venueID, concat(c.path, '/', v.venueName), c.depth + 1
    from cte c
    inner join tblAdmVenueLink l on l.mainVenueID = c.venueID
    inner join tblAdmVenue v on v.venueID = l.subVenueID
)
select * from cte order by path
```

The anchor of the recursive query selects top nodes (ie rows whose ids do not exist in column `subVenueID` of the link table). Then, the recursive part follows the relations.

As a bonus, I  added a `level` column that represents the depth of each node, starting at 0 for top nodes.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4b563dd1558223f1e9c01b69a95827b)**:

```
venueID | venueName       | mainVenueID | path                       | depth
:------ | :-------------- | :---------- | :------------------------- | ----:
LA47    | Banquet         | null        | Banquet                    |     0
LA43    | Big Room        | null        | Big Room                   |     0
LA45    | Room Daisy      | LA43        | Big Room/Room Daisy        |     1
LA46    | Room Rose       | LA43        | Big Room/Room Rose         |     1
LA48    | Split 1         | LA46        | Big Room/Room Rose/Split 1 |     2
LA44    | Hall            | null        | Hall                       |     0
LA49    | Meeting Room WP | LA44        | Hall/Meeting Room WP       |     1
```

Answer (score 1):

For  your data you can use this:
To display this correctly, you can use a SEPARATPR like comma, and split the returned data, and check the hirarchy

> ```
> -- schema
> CREATE TABLE tblAdmVenue (
>     venueID VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
>     venueName VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY(venueID)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE tblAdmVenueLink (
>     venueLinkID VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
>     mainVenueID VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
>     subVenueID VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY(venueLinkID)
>     -- FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentId) REFERENCES Departments(Id)
> );
>
> -- data
> INSERT INTO tblAdmVenue (venueID, venueName)
> VALUES ('LA43', 'Big Room'), ('LA44', 'Hall'),
>        ('LA45', 'Room Daisy'), ('LA46', 'Room Rose'),
>        ('LA47', 'Banquet'), ('LA48', 'Split 1'),
>        ('LA49', 'Meeting Room WP');
>
> INSERT INTO tblAdmVenueLink (venueLinkID, mainVenueID, subVenueID)
> VALUES ('1', 'LA43', 'LA45'), ('2', 'LA43', 'LA46'),
>        ('3', 'LA46', 'LA48'), ('4', 'LA44', 'LA49');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> with recursive cte (subVenueID, mainVenueID,level) as (
>   select     subVenueID,
>              mainVenueID, 1 as level
>   from       tblAdmVenueLink
>   union
>   select     p.subVenueID,
>              cte.mainVenueID,
>              cte.level+1
>   from       tblAdmVenueLink p
>   inner join cte
>           on p.mainVenueID = cte.subVenueID
> )
> select 
>    
>     CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(b.venueName  ORDER BY level DESC SEPARATOR  '-->') ,'-->',a.venueName)
> from cte c 
> LEFT JOIN tblAdmVenue a ON a.venueID = c.subVenueID 
> LEFT JOIN tblAdmVenue b ON b.venueID = c.mainVenueID
> GROUP BY subVenueID;
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(b.venueName  ORDER BY level DESC SEPARATOR  '-->') ,'-->',a.venueName) |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Big Room-->Room Daisy                                                                      |
> | Big Room-->Room Rose                                                                       |
> | Big Room-->Room Rose-->Split 1                                                             |
> | Hall-->Meeting Room WP                                                                     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=073254430cf631c335e06323110a051d)*

Comment: can you help me to get an order like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sx7cr315/) please.

Comment: I can't make an order because there is no deterministic way to determine which comes first. I don't know and i can't get the information Why Banquet comes first. , if you provide this information in another table or add a field to your tables, i cam change it to fit.

Comment: If I add more data in `tblAdmVenueLink` [new data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c6ece/9) where `mainVenueID` == `subVenueID` meaning is a parent, its possible to make an order like I wanted?

Comment: You take the list tblAdmVenue   and tell friends or family to sort the list, now you see nobody can do it without any orientation. I think you should take a really, really good look at [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL] (http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and rethink your approach

Answer (score 0):

Use only one table, not two.  The first table has all the info needed.

Then start the CTE with the rows `WHERE mainVenueID IS NULL`, no `JOIN` needed.

This may be a good tutorial:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660789/1766831

Its 'forest' is close to what you want.

Comment: If i only use one table without join, how can I get the `mainVenueID` from `tblAdmVenueLink`.. Refer to my data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf72b/6)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have:

1. table tblAdmVenue A is the venue list; and
2. table tblAdmVenueLink B is the tree relation table for parent-child

For your question on how to get a correct sorting order, I think one of the trick is to concatenate the parent venue names.

```sql
with q0(venueID, venueName, mainVenueID, venuePath) as (
  select
    A.venueID,
    A.venueName,
    null,
    A.venueName
  from tblAdmVenue A
       left join tblAdmVenue B on A.venueID = B.subVenueID
  where B.mainVenueID is null
  union all
  select
    A.venueID,
    A.venueName,
    q0.venueID,
    q0.venuePath + char(9) + A.venueName
  from q0
       inner join tblAdmVenue B on q0.venueID = B.mainVenueID
       inner join tblAdmVenue A on A.venueID = B.subVenueID
)
select venueID, venueName, mainVenueID
from q0
order by venuePath
```